# Django traceback / cannot import name 'TypeVarTuple' from 'typing_extensions'

Tags: python, django

Hi all I'm new to django & python.
I keep getting this traceback while using django when I tried runserver or migrate.

```
   ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeVarTuple' from 'typing_extensions'
```

I already tried

1/ upgrading django with pip

2/ upgrading typing extensions with pip

and both didn't work for me...

Did anyone faced the same problem and solved?

Thank you!

Comment: Based on the [souce](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/typing_extensions/src_py3/typing_extensions.py) **TypeVar** and **Tuple** are separate things imported from **typing**.

Comment: You could have at least shown a code snippet.

Comment: Did you create a virtual environment, like `python -m venv` or `poetry`?